# How can I return a 404 with a response body when no route matches in NET Core 3?

Tags: c#, api, .net-core, routes, backend

I've got a .NET Core 3 API and I'd like to return a 404 with a ResponseBody when no match has been found for a given request.

If the URL is wrong, I'd like to return the following in the body of the 404:

```
{
    "errorCode":  "678",
    "message": "resource inexistent"
}
```

The out of the box behavior is returning a 404 with no body. I need to send info on the ResponseBody about the error for troubleshooting.

I've seen here that it was rather easy to do with WebAPI.
https://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/handling-http-404-error-in-asp-net-web-api

Is there a way to this with NET Core?

Comment: You can intercept error with the custom error middleware, from there you can return what ever you whant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .Net core you can use a middleware to rewrite your response.

you can inbuilt UseStatusCodes middleware, when you use this middleware it triggers for status codes from 400 - 599, you can customize you response using this middleware. Below is a sample code where I changed the status code of 404 to 500 and return the response with custom defined body.

```
app.UseStatusCodePages(async context =>
            {
                if (context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode == 404)
                {
                    var noContentResponse = new NoContentResponse
                    {
                        errorCode = "678",
                        message = "resource inexistent"
                    };
                    var responeString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(noContentResponse);
                    var requestContent = new StringContent(responeString);
                    requestContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
                    context.HttpContext.Response.Body = await requestContent.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                    context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 500;
                }
            });
```

you can do more with middleware, please check below blogs which has good explaination on handling errors in .net core.

Reference

- Here is nice blog which explains exception handling. You can make use some of the default middlewares.
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-3.1
- https://andrewlock.net/re-execute-the-middleware-pipeline-with-the-statuscodepages-middleware-to-create-custom-error-pages/
- https://medium.com/@matteocontrini/consistent-error-responses-in-asp-net-core-web-apis-bb70b435d1f8

Answer (score 0):

Using .NET Core's IActionResult, you can return a new `NotFoundObjectResult` like so:

```cs
public IActionResult MyMethod() 
{
    var data = new {hello = "World"};
    return new NotFoundObjectResult(data);
}
```